# last selection elevates all in table instead of just that row

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into another little snag and I am kind of lost of what would make this a unique call for each row.

Here is my query

```
$myChoice=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM  player_clinics
INNER JOIN tourneys
ON player_clinics.tourney_id =tourneys.tid
WHERE  player_id = '$player_id'
ORDER BY tourney_start_date
");
```

This is my if statement

```
if ($selected  == 'Y' && $entered=='Y' && $paid =='Y' && $player_id == $pid) 
    {$we_entered = '<font color="#FF0000">Accepted</font>'; $we_paid= '<font color="#009900">Paid</font>';}
```

works fine for the first selection but if the last selection is marked Y then all of the choices elevate to $we_selected = Y The same happens for $we_paid as well

here is the tables. tid and tourney_id are the same value so I can have a unique when needed

player_clinics table

```
player_clinic_id, player_id, tid, selected, paid, entered
       402          526      465      Y
       403          526      388      Y       Y      Y
```

tourney table

```
  tid,  tourney_name
  465    mytourney
  388   yourtourney
```

Comment: Error message supression.. Don't you think you should fix the errors before worrying about your resultsets?

Comment: Are you resetting `$we_entered` back to `''` and `$we_paid` back to `''` after each iteration?

Comment: @SetSailMedia That was it, I totally forgot that. Throw me an answer and I will mark it solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is part of a larger code block where you're looping through the result set, you need to reset the variables after (or before) each iteration.

```
while(){
    [...]

    unset( $we_entered ); // or $we_entered = ''; depending on your usage
    unset( $we_paid ); // or $we_paid = '';

    if ($selected  == 'Y' && $entered=='Y' && $paid =='Y' && $player_id == $pid) 
    {$we_entered = '<font color="#FF0000">Accepted</font>'; $we_paid= '<font color="#009900">Paid</font>'; }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: you saved my last 2 hairs :)

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a fresh pair of eyes to look at it from ;)